# How to compare two objects in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I have two User objects `existing_user, current_user`, how should I traverse the `User.attributes.keys` and check if they are equal.

Comment: Do you want to get true/false or do you want to know which attributes are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  # untested, but the logic seems sound.
  def equals?(user)
    User.attributes.keys.each do |k|          
      return false unless self[k] == user[k]
    end
    true
  end

end
```

You could then call `current_user.equals?(existing_user)`.

Comment: There is no point in looping through attributes if return doesn't specify which attribute is different. You can just do existing_user.eql?(current_user) instead, given that they are of the same class. Otherwise it will always return false.

Comment: That's incorrect. Return doesn't need to specify which attrib is different.

Comment: My point exactly, there are already methods called eql? and equal? no point in overwriting it.

Comment: His question, and I will repeat, was "How should I traverse the `User.attributes.keys` and check if they are equal." Although, yes, both solutions work in practice, he was asking how it is actually done.

Answer (score 0):

The background of this question is not completely clear to me. Usually when one is refering to `current_user` like you do, the background is ruby-on-rails, not only ruby like stated in the subject. I *guess*, you are getting the `current_user` via an external login-process (cas, facebook, etc) and internally keep a user-table for additional attributes.

Given my assumption is true, I would recommend, to identify one uniq attribute of the **external** user-model and store it in your internal user-table. You might want to validate this attributes uniqueness. When making your comparison, restrict to comparing this single attribute on the externally logged-in user and the internally kept users.